# HTML page is showing blank maybe for bootstrap cdn links

Tags: php, html, css

This page is not showing in the browser, Only my header is displaying. I want to display the form and show the PHP value from the database. But when I click on the edit page on editpost.php then this page is not showing any data.

```
     <?php 
include "../admin/inc/header.php";
// include "../helpers/functions.php";
?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="add-post-form">
                <?php
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $userHandler = new userHandler();
                $getPost = $userHandler->selectPost($id);
                if ($id != null && isset($_POST['update'])) {
                    $updatePost = $userHandler->updatePost($id, $_POST['title'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['body']);
                }
                ?>
                <form action="editpost.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="title" class="mt-2">Title</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $getPost['title']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="date" class="mt-2">Select Date</label>
                        <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $getPost['date']; ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="mainpost" class="mt-2">Main Post</label>
                        <textarea name="body" id="mainpost" class="form-control">  <?php echo $getPost['body']; ?> </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to clear the cookies and server cache. If it doesn't works, view the external php script for any uncompleted functions (I mean missing `}` or `;` characters).

Comment: I have checked all , and browser console is showing this error:Cookie “PHPSESSID” will be soon treated as cross-site cookie against “http://localhost/bootstrapblog/admin/editpost.php?id=2” because the scheme does not match. 2 editpost.php
GEThttps://getbootstrap.com/dashboard.css
[HTTP/2 404 Not Found 100ms]

Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled 
The resource from “https://getbootstrap.com/dashboard.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Comment: Did you try to load the pure html page or use inline css? I mean without any php code... It may be a problem with external links. Did you declare the updatePost() function? Or just get the input content by $_POST['id'] method, then process it into the database

Comment: Yes, I have a custom function updatePost() , but it working in another page except here.